# how to set up coupon for a free product with purchases at least of $75 in Magento 1.7?

Tags: magento, coupon

We are trying to make it so that customers can receive 100% off on a product (SKU is 1PR) once they have done the following:

- entered it in to their cart
- entered at least $75 worth of product in their cart
- entered the promo code “peonia”

We have duplicated promo code settings that worked for us back in December (see what we entered in the "actions" tab under shopping cart conditions below of our attempt).  Currently, this doesn’t work and customers see an error message ("coupon code “peonia” is not valid") after clicking “apply coupon”.

Any ideas?

If you have an idea for settings that would make it so that customers receive a free product w/o having to include it in their cart, that would be welcome as an alternative solution to our problem.

Here's what we have in "Actions" that isn't working (but it worked back in December):

Discount Amount is 100

if ALL of these conditions are TRUE

Price in cart equals or greater than 75

SKU is 1PR

Answer (score 1):

In Action you need to do :

Type : %
Amount : 100
Maximum 1 product
Condition SKU is 1PR

And in Condition tab you have :

IF ALL THESE CONDITION ARE TRUE
   Sub Selection of Product
   Total amount >= 75 For a subselection Having ALL THESE Conditions 
       SKU is not 1PR

If you have > $75 for all except 1PR you have 100% discount on 1PR